# value of @docRoot in grails project

Tags: grails, javadoc

Using `@docRoot` annotation as javadoc annotation, i want to add logo of our company on each documentation , so i add this snippet :

```
<img src="{@docRoot}/logo.png">
```

However,Preview of javadoc don't display logo image.

Where should i put `logo.png` image to be displayed in javadoc :

```
 1. ./myproject/
 2. ./myproject/web-app/
 3. ./myproject/web-app/images/
 4. or where...
```

i try to put it at `./myproject/` but in vain

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would want to stick it in an images folder located under web-app. An example path would be:

```
myproject/web-app/images/skin/<YOUR LOGOS>
```

That should enable `url(../images/skin/<YOUR LOGOS>)` to work.

edit: The above solution assumes you are calling for logos and images from your CSS.